# Attaching VisualSVN Server to an existing repository

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn-server, svn-repository

All the recent VisualSVN Server posts made me want to check it out. I have SVN running right now through Apache, but I'd like to try out VisualSVN Server, mostly for the Active Directory integration. Their docs don't describe whether you can easily migrate an existing repository.

Anyone done this before?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server) will use your existing SVN repositories with no problems. I have successfully migrated repositories from SVN + Apache to VisualSVN Server on multiple occasions.

Comment: I had the same question. For exact details look at this post.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615728/import-dumped-svn-repo-into-visual-svn

Answer (score 5):

There is an option on the VisualSVN Server Manager console to import an existing repository. You just give it the existing repository location and a name for the imported repository.  Pretty simple.

Answer (score 2):

An SVN server doesn't really 'attach' to a repository, it just needs to be able to see its files.  The repository itself doesn't know or care if it's being accessed via svnserve, Apache mod_svn or direct file:// URLs

Answer (score 1):

There is a VisualSVN Server Knowledge Base article about the case:

[**How can I import my existing repository into newly installed VisualSVN Server?**](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/)

[image]