# Import dumped SVN repo into VisualSVN Server

Tags: svn, import, backup, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I have dumped my repository on my old computer to a file with the command.
`svnadmin dump C:\myrepo/ > mydumpfile`

Now I decided to use [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) on my new computer as opposed to just a baseline subversion. How do I import my repository into VisualSVN Server?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Figured it out now that Andrew Clark pointed out there is a "All Tasks"

```
Repository -> All Tasks -> Open Command Prompt

svnadmin create repository-name
svnadmin load repository-name < repository-name.dmp
```

Comment: repository-name argument in the form of: "C:/myrepo/"
You can also use the "--parent-dir" argument to specify a directory to import the dump file into.

Comment: This will not work with the versions 2.6 and later! See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49414335/761095

Answer (score 4):

try copying your repository to like C:\Repositories

or use Repositories -> All Tasks -> Import Existing Repository

Comment: Hmm the problem is it is not a repository folder structure right now, it is just the dump file.

Comment: try to just copy the old one over rather than dumping

Comment: Did you ever find an answer

Answer (score 1):

Importing from portable dump file implemented in [VisualSVN Server 3.2](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/3.2/):

1. Start the **VisualSVN Server Manager** console.
2. Select **Import Existing Repository** command in the context menu for the **Repositories** node.
3. Select **Load repository from dump file**, click **Next**.
4. Enter path to dump file and click **Next**.

Do not forget to configure SVN permissions for the imported repository.

[image: Screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

If you ask this question in context of repository backups, consider this answer, please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12444944/761095.

> When you want to import an existing repository to VisualSVN Server,
>   read the article [KB10: How can I import my existing repository into
>   newly installed VisualSVN Server?](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/). However, when you migrating an
>   existing VisualSVN Server installation to a new server computer, read
>   the article [KB166: Migrating VisualSVN Server to another
>   computer](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00166/).

You have two options to import an existing repository: use the **Import Existing Repository Wizard** command in the VisualSVN Server Manager console or use the [`Import-SvnRepository`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Import-SvnRepository) PowerShell cmdlet.

### Use VisualSVN Server Manager to import the repository dump

Follow these steps to import the dump file via VisualSVN Server Manager:

1. Start the **VisualSVN Server Manager** console.
2. Right-click **Repositories** and click **Import Existing Repository**.
3. Click **Load repository from a dump file** and click **Next**.
4. Enter the path to the dump file or click Browse to select it. Click **Next**.
5. Enter the name of the new repository and click **Next**.
6. Select the repository permissions and click **Import**. Wait for the import process to finish.
   [image]
7. When the import process is complete, click **Finish**.
   [image]

### Use PowerShell to import the repository dump

Follow these steps to import the dump file via PowerShell:

1. [Start the **PowerShell** console](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00165/).
2. Execute the following command and wait for the import process to finish:

   ```
   Import-SvnRepository PATH-TO-DUMP-FILE -DestinationName NEW-REPO-NAME
   ```

   [image]