# VisualSVN dump a repository project

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svndump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import Dumped SVN Repo into Visual SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615728/import-dumped-svn-repo-into-visual-svn)

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this. I followed VisualSVN recommendation ([here](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00017/)) when setting up my repository locally. I am now migrating to an external party (codebaseHQ). How can I dump a project from the repository for the migration.

I no longer need all the projects in VisualSVN server. I only need one. I can't find info on how to dump just a project (e.g Application1 in the link above).

Comment: Do you have a file system SVN application installed, such as Tortoise SVN? I am not sure if this is possible with just VisualSVN.

Comment: I have Tortoise SVN installed on my development box but not on the server running VisualSVN Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dump a project you can use the `svnadmin` tool in your VisualSVN Server directory.

You should be able to find it at `%VISUALSVN_SERVER%\bin\svnadmin.exe`