# making an independent copy of svn repository

Tags: svn

I am trying to make a clone of a repository but it should be independent copy of each other. Is there any magic behind this or just use a svn client and make a clone of it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Keep in mind that when you do this, there is no link between the original and the clone, and you can't merge changes between them as you can with a DVCS like hg or git.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try [`svnadmin hotcopy`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.hotcopy.html).  You can look it up in the [repo maintenance section](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk) of the svn book *(Version Control with Subversion*), specifically in the section ["repository replication"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication).  There is also the `svnsync` command, but you only need this if you're trying to create a mirror.

To quote the book: "simply doing a recursive directory copy runs the risk of generating a faulty backup. In the case of Berkeley DB, the documentation describes a certain order in which database files can be copied that will guarantee a valid backup copy. A similar ordering exists for FSFS data." FSFS and Berkeley DB are the two database options that normal subversion installations provide, and FSFS is the default.

Example usage (again from book):

```
$ svnadmin hotcopy /var/svn/repos /var/svn/repos-backup
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`svnrdump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.tk.svnrdump) tool to get repository dump (complete revision history) over HTTPS and svn:// (i.e. remotely) and `svnadmin load` it into a new clean repository. Note that in order to get the complete repository dump you must have full Read access to all trees in the repository, otherwise the dump can be incomplete.

Answer (score 2):

I am trying to do the same thing, basically what I have done is the following:

**svnadmin dump** (with optional `-r (revision number)`), I've used it to dump the latest revision of our code and then loaded just the latest revision, but if you need the entire history of who did what, then the command is without -r.

**Dump** the current repo:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/repository > repo.dmp
```

**Create a new** (yet empty) repository:

```
svnadmin create /path/to/new/repo
```

And then **load the dump** into new repository:

```
svnadmin load /path/to/new/repo < repo.dmp
```