# SVNAdmin Load is not working

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

So I created dump files for my old repositories.
Now moving these to new server.

When I use VisualSVN admin interface to import using

Import Existing Repository --> Load Repository from a dump file

Then it is fine. I am able to access new repository on new server.

But if I use command line

```
svnadmin create test
svnadmin load test < test.dump
```

Then I am not able to access this test repository from Tortoise SVN ( it won't show up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you should usually use the **Import Existing Repository** wizard in the **VisualSVN Server Manager** console to import your Subversion repositories.
[image]

However, when you want to import the repositories from command line or in batch, you can use [VisualSVN Server PowerShell](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/). Use the [`Import-SvnRepository`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#Import-SvnRepository) PowerShell cmdlet to import the dump. You can also use the [`New-SvnRepository`](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00088/#New-SvnRepository) PowerShell cmdlet to create new repositories.

[image]

Standard `svnadmin create` does not add authorization files /conf/VisualSVN-WinAuthz.ini or /conf/VisualSVN-SvnAuthz.ini to the repository. These files must be in place for the authorization to work.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I needed