# How to reinstall SVN using the existing repo files from previous install?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, restore, visualsvn-server

<sup>Preface: After upgrading from Windows 7 to 10, things didn't go well. It seemed to go fine, but I was occasionally getting a black screen on boot. I turned off the PC and my registry got irreversibly corrupted. I have now reinstalled Windows 10 cleanly. All is working well after a month, but now I need to get SVN back up.</sup>

The 'proper' backup I have of my repos is too old. I need to ensure backups are done more frequently moving forwards. What I do have is the entire disk partition I had SVN data stored on.

The file structure on the SVN partition is intact, e.g. `X:/MyRepo/db/revs` and all the data on `X:`. I also have the latest copy of `C:/MyRepo` where my working copy was stored.

How can I reinstall TortoiseSVN using my existing files (not a backup), and retain commit history including log messages?

Comment: Subversion is a *centralized* source control system (almost every command goes back to the repository and the repository has the commit history and log messages). If you have all the data from the *repository* (`x:`), but your *working copy* (`c:`) is from an old backup, you might need to check out a new working copy.

Comment: @crashmstr I have all the data from the repository (`X:`). The partition is still there, intact. `C:` got completely wiped. So the question is how I can reinstall VisualSVN using the existing repo partition.

Comment: I have never used VisualSVN, but you should be able to just install it then configure it for where your repository is stored on your `x:` drive.

Comment: Possible solutions: [Attaching VisualSVN Server to an existing repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774/attaching-visualsvn-server-to-an-existing-repository), [VisualSVN Support page for "import"](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00010/)

Comment: To give some closure to this, the dupe worked. In particular the 2nd answer - "There is an option on the VisualSVN Server Manager console to import an existing repository".

Answer (score 0):

Just install TortoiseSVN (or any other SVN-client), and use old repositories (maybe relocation of WC will be needed due to changed path), if *the whole repo-tree* isn't broken somehow

Comment: The machine acted as both the server and client. I need to reinstall the server first. The question is how to do that.

Comment: @DannyBeckett - **which** server? Apache or svnserve?

Comment: It's VisualSVN Server so Apache Subversion.